# another test of atom feed read fails

Tags: c#, .net, atom-feed

I am using this function public static

```
    IList<Item> ParseAtom(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);

            // Feed/Entry
            var entries = from item in doc.Root.Elements().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "entry")
                          select new Item
                          {
                              FeedType = FeedType.Atom,
                              Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "content").Value,
                              Link = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                              PublishDate = ParseDate(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "published").Value),
                              Title = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value
                          };

            return entries.ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<Item>();
        }
    }
```

I am using the following link
http://localhost/posts.atom/

When i open that link in the browser I see the list of links that direct me to each post item.

1. 1  Link 2  Link 3  Link 4  Link

but I when I use it as a url to parse, my program return nothing. I suppose myself that I don't understand what the link above actually means. I really need any of your help to offer me somemore explanation of atom feed, thank you very much .

The XML is created by another file that is stored as a stream as in the following format

```
<Root>
  <Child id=123456>
     <Child1>Child1
     </Child1>  
     <Child2>Child2
     </Child2>  
  </Child>
</Root>
```

Comment: It's impossible for us to help much without knowing what the feed looks like - you've given a localhost link, which is obviously only going to work on your machine. Note that you're using a very clumsy way of finding elements with a given name - you should use `Element(XName)` having created the right name from an `XNamespace` and the local name.

Comment: `what the feed looks like` what does that mean ? Could you explain or offer me an example ?

Comment: The XML - put some sample XML into your question.

Comment: Also note that it could well be that there's just an exception - the fact that you're masking all exceptions by returning an empty list without even logging makes it hard to diagnose issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that an exception is being thrown - but you can't tell because you're "handling" *all* exceptions by returning an empty list, without recording what the exception is or *any* kind of diagnostics. I would personally remove the try/catch altogether: if something is wrong, why hide that? If you *must* catch the exception, then catch *specific* exceptions, and log them so you know what's happened.

Your query can be simplified considerably, too:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("atom.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

var entries = doc.Root
                 .Elements(ns + "entry")
                 .Select(item => new Item
                 {
                      FeedType = FeedType.Atom,
                      Content = (string) item.Element(ns + "content"),
                      Link = (string) item.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href"),
                      PublishDate = (DateTime) item.Element(ns + "published"),
                      Title = (string) item.Element(ns + "title")
                  };
```

Note that this will now set Content and Title to null if those elements don't exist; change to using `.Value` again if you would rather it threw an exception. You can get the same behaviour for `PublishDate` by casting to `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`, obviously after changing the type of the property too. Handling absent links would be slightly harder, but not too bad - let me know if you want a hand there.

Basically I suspect it's an absent element - quite possibly `published`. It'll be easier to find out when you're logging (or not catching) exceptions though.

EDIT: Given your comment, it sounds like this has absolutely nothing to do with how you're handling the XML - it's *loading* the XML that's causing the problem. This is where not swallowing exceptions is important...

I don't know of any way to provide credentials when loading XML via `XDocument.Load` - you may well need to use `WebRequest` or `WebClient` to fetch the data, then parse it with `XDocument.Load(Stream)`.

Comment: Thank you, but I have got an exception stating tat I cant connect to the remote server. Actually my server needs authentication (password and username to log in before letting the user view the gridview data). I don't know where in the code should I put my username as well as my password. Thank you alot if you offer me more hints about this.

Comment: @Mikhail: Right, so it's got *nothing to do with the XML parsing*. See my edit.

Comment: No, you helped. the file extension I missed. It should have been the above url+'.xml'. The above code could read the data or not is unknown as I obtain an connection issue. I am thankful if you will tell me more about this.

Comment: @Mikhail: About what? You haven't provided nearly enough information for me to be able to help you, I'm afraid. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints